# Huge Server: Backing Up Many TB of Data with Instant Failover?

Tags: backup, cdp, snapshot

We have a very challenging system to back up:
1. We have 20 TB of data right now.
2. Each month we get another 3 TB of data, and about 5 TB of data changes each month.
3. We are currently a Windows-based shop and use DELL MD1000 systems.

We want to:
- Fail over in real time to the most recent backup copy of the data.
- Be able to restore previous versions of the data for the past 60 days.

NOTES:
- Because of all the writing and re-writing to disk, file corruption is fairly common, so snapshots that don't duplicate data and not very useful.
- Keep in mind that decompressing 2 TB of data in order to restore would result in days of downtime. Even just copying the data could take forever.

** What possible solutions do we have? **

Answer (score 0):

For dull technical reasons I don't normally recommend NetApp boxes but I think for this situation they'd be ideal. You could basically just snapshot the volumes every *N* minutes, it's what they do best - you can then just mirror the whole drive to another location or whatever for DR and run a tape/disk backup from either side.

That's not huge by the way, not small though :)

Comment: Chopper - would that be a good solution if the data was, say, a DB of some sort? The OP didn't say that this was files, he just called it "data".

Comment: yep, you can quiesce the DB in sync with the snap.